# Magento 2.4.0 - Configurable Product Showing Out of Stock

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.4, indexing, out-of-stock

We have Multiple configurable products but some of the Configurable Products are showing as Out of Stock.

I have verified the following Multiple times

- All children are In Stock & have a quantity greater than 0.
- Configurable product is in Stock
- Manage Stock settings (of Parent & child products)

$_product->isAvailable(); returning false in case of configurable Product(Out of Stock).

**Note**:
Not confirmed but we are running the GTM Scripts outside the Magento (maybe it is triggering this issue but not confirmed.

**Temporary Solution:**

Admin -> Catalog -> Open any child product and just hit the save button.
Now Configurable product again showing in stock...
The issue got fixed temporarily and then reappear at any other time.

**Secondly**
The issue also not appeared if I create a new product following the same content and settings as of the existing product.
But we have multiple configurable products and we need to apply the fixes to existing products without recreating them all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the indexer commands -

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento indexer:status  //to check the indexer status
php bin/magento indexer:reset   //Use this to invalidate the status of all indexers
```

Reference link - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html

then check all the child products have qty & they are added in main website and visibility set to Not Visible Individually.

Comment: Followed all steps but still same.

Comment: check all the the variants status & parent product is in stock.